# How to use Walmart returns API?

Tags: curl, php-curl, walmart-api

I am attempting to GET to the Walmart Returns API using CURL in PHP.

https://developer.walmart.com/tryout/us/mp/returns

for some reason, it does not accept my method or it returns errors like...

```
 INVALID_REQUEST.GMP_ORDER_API requestParam
 Could not find acceptable representation
 Request invalid.
```

Here is my code:

```
$getTokenUrl='https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/token';    
$client_id=CLIENT_ID;
$secret_key=SECETE_KEY;
$authorization_key=base64_encode($client_id.":".$secret_key);

$generated_corelation_id=md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$Tokenheaders = array(
        'Authorization:Basic '.$authorization_key,
        'WM_SVC.NAME:Walmart Marketplace',
        'WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID:'.$generated_corelation_id,
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );
    
$createString='grant_type=client_credentials';  

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $getTokenUrl,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $createString,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $Tokenheaders,
));

$accessToken = curl_exec($curl);

$accessToken = trim($accessToken);

$result = explode('<\/accessToken>',json_encode($accessToken));
$accessToken=str_replace( '"', "", $result[0] );


$generateToken    = explode('<accessToken>',trim($accessToken));
$updateData['generateToken']    = $generateToken[1];


$header=array(
    'Authorization: AUTH',
    'WM_SEC.ACCESS_TOKEN: '.$generateToken[1],
    'WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: '.trim($generated_corelation_id),
    'WM_SVC.NAME: Walmart Marketplace',
    'Content-Type: application/xml',
    'Cookie: TS01f4281b=01c5a4e2f9d2e37f503c87a5acab256d9aa105b3dfa312ae726f9a85fa0e52b76d3fa46124800be0568fc6d32e9e54cb0d3ab31120'
  );

$url='https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/returns';

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Try removing the Content-Type in the headers for the GET request and add "Accept" as application/json (or application/xml if they support that)

Answer (score 0):

`WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID`  uses  `guid`, not  `md5`